# FileRun gives HTTP 500 white page when trying to install

Tags: php, iis

I'm trying to install [FileRun](http://filerun.com/) on Windows Server 2016 using PHP in IIS, but I keep getting a blank page. Looking in the Chrome Dev Tools, it's actually an HTTP 500 error and nothing is loading. There are no errors in the php log and failed request tracing in IIS has no details either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were a few problems that caused this.

1. As of this writing, the highest version supported is the PHP 7.0.X branch, since ionCube doesn't support VC15.
2. Use the ionCube `loader-wizard.php` wizard, which will detect the right zipped dlls to download.
3. Assuming you have PHP installed at `C:\Program Files\PHP\7.0.26`, place the ionCube dlls in the `C:\Program Files\PHP\7.0.26\ext` folder. Be sure to delete the `loader-wizard.php` file.
4. Grant full control to the FileRun `system\data` folder to `IUSR`. Note that granting to the group `IIS_USRS` won't work, as PHP is impersonating the legacy `IUSR` account.
5. Since I already had the `woff` and `woff2` MIME types defined at the server level (which I think was by default in Windows Server 2016), remove the web.config at the root of FileRun since IIS will complain about the types being re-declared.

Comment: Note that ionCube builds follow and match the official PHP releases on php.net.  
PHP 7.0 is released as a VC14 build so the Loaders are built with VC14.
PHP 7.2 is released as a VC15 build and so the Loaders for PHP 7.2 are built with VC15.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now.